# How can I grab the ID of the just deleted record?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This code is intended to grab the ID of the deleted record, the user who deleted the record, and the date and time the record was deleted and insert it into a hostical table.

So far, once a record is deleted, the code grabs more than one deleted record.

Please see my code and what I am doing wrong.

Thanks alot in advance for your help.

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeletedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleted 
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Constr").ConnectionString 
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection 
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand 
    Dim sql As String = "" 

    ' Indicate whether the delete operation succeeded.  

        If e.Exception Is Nothing Then 

            Dim strID As String = GridView1.FindControl("ID").Cells(1).Text 
            'Who deleted a record? 
            sql += "Insert into Archives ([ID],[choice],[date_stamp],[approved],[chcknum],[DeletedBy],[dateDeleted]) " 
            sql += " SELECT [ID],[choice],[date_stamp],[approved],[chcknum],[login],getDate() from Depends " 
            sql += " inner join  Emp on Depends.employee_id = Emp.employee_id where login ='" & Session.Item("UserName").ToString & "' and upass = '" & Session.Item("Password").ToString & "' and [ID] = '" & strID & "' " 
        End If 
    Response.Write(sql) 
    Response.End() 
    Try 
        cnn = New SqlConnection(connStr) 

        cnn.Open() 
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn) 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        cmd.Dispose() 
        sql = "" 
    Catch ex As SqlException 
        Dim errorMsg As String = "Error in Updation" 
        errorMsg += ex.Message 
        Throw New Exception(errorMsg) 
    Finally 
        cnn.Close() 
    End Try 
End Sub
```

My problem, I think, lies in this line of code:

Dim strID As String = GridView1.FindControl("ID").Cells(1).Text

I don't think it is correct.

Comment: why don't you just find the ID before you delete it ?

Comment: Hi Shivan. Can you please show me how or atleast an example of how to do that? I have this on the markup:                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" Visible = "false"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
and this:             <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for the [GridView.DataKeys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y421). Use it to tell your GridView which column(s) in the data is should use as an unique identifer.

You probably also want to look into a few other optimzations for your code:

- Use parameters in your query, don't concatenate a SQL statement like that.
- Use the [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) with your SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects for proper and easy disposal.
- You're not achiving anything with the try-catch, in fact you're obscuring the exception stack.

Update:

See the [GridViewDeletedEventArgs.Keys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeletedeventargs.keys.aspx) to get the ID of the deleted row. Is the "ID" column part of the query you're using to bind the GridView?

Here's a better (complete) example:

.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind, with some dummy data:

```
Public Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      Dim x() = {New With {.id = 1, .name = "xxx"}, New With {.id = 2, .name = "zzz"}}
      GridView1.DataSource = x
      GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    Dim id As Integer = CInt(e.Keys(0))
    ' Do your stuff!
    ' Don't forget to rebind the GridView, it will still have the deleted row in Viewstate.
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's exactly correct Jakob and this is what I am using:    Dim StrID = GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Item("ID").ToString() but I just kept getting error that RowIndex is not a member of system.web.ui... What do I need to change in the code?

Comment: Thank you very much for those tips. I am still very confused about how to obtain GridViewDeledEventArgs.Keys Property. I have looked at the links. The users delete one row at a time. So, how do I pass the ID datakey to the select statement with the WhERE [ID} = ' &" strID & "'

Comment: You are absolutely God Sent. Thank you Jakob. Now, I am getting the ID of deleted record but for some reason, now it is no longer inserting the data into archives. It was doing that before. So, I should be using row_Deleting, not row_deleted?

Comment: Also, Jakob, when I run the debugger, I am getting duplicate entries.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with your SQL than getting the ID from the GridView. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience sir. You are indeed a good man. Everything is inserting, except it is inserting double. I will try and work this out. Meanwhile, if you still have a time, can you please take a look at my sql? Still the same at the top that I am using. Really grateful for you helping me get this far.

Comment: I don't see why you need to join in the Employees table: Just get the userid and use it in your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running SQL Server, It might be easier to use a delete trigger on the table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx

...deleted and inserted are logical (conceptual) tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is attempted, and hold the old values or new values of the rows that may be changed by the user action.